# 100% CPU used in javapns

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications

i'm working for a project send notification to iPhone. and i used javapns. but when i invork the message:

```
pushManager.sendNotification(client, complexPayLoad);
```

i found the message cannot return correctly, and it cause cpu usage become 100%.
could anybody tell me where's wrong about my code? Thanks.

more completement code

```
try {
        // create a complex PayLoad with a custom alert
        PayLoad complexPayLoad = new PayLoad();
        PayLoadCustomAlert customAlert = new PayLoadCustomAlert();
        customAlert.addBody(message);
        complexPayLoad.addCustomAlert(customAlert);
        complexPayLoad.addSound("chime");
        for (String key : new HashSet<String>(data.keySet())) {
            complexPayLoad.addCustomDictionary(key, (String)data.get(key));
        }

        try {
            // Link iPhone's UDID (64-char device token) to a stringName
            pushManager.addDevice(token, token);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Perhaps we added duplicate devices
            log.debug("Perhaps we added duplicate devices");
        }

        // Get iPhone client
        Device client = pushManager.getDevice(token);

        // Send message
        pushManager.sendNotification(client, complexPayLoad);
        log.info("Message sent!"); // i cannot get this message

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: i check the sourcecode of javapns. i found i hanged at here in sendNotification method: `logger.debug( "Notification sent" ); logger.debug( "In: [" + in.readLine() + "]" ); while ( ! this.socket.isInputShutdown() ) { while( in.ready() ) { logger.debug("ready now"); logger.debug(in.readLine()); System.out.println( this.socket.getInputStream().read() ); } }`

Answer (score 0):

What version?

Version 2 just came out, and fixed a number of issues.

It is also much easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.my version is 1.6.9. yes, and it's okay when i test under the javapns 2.0 beta. but it seems cannot support http proxy correctly.